# support semi-translucent for MapFragment (Google Maps Android API v2)

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-2

I'd like to show a semi-translucent map (using Google Maps Android API v2) on screen, so I use View.setAlpha() but it does not work for MapFragment.

Does anyone know how to do that?